# Tsx luxon type of DateTime

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, tsx, luxon

I have dates in `luxon` format, when I try to print information from the console it tells me this:

[image]

I get the following error `TS2339: Property 'c' does not exist on type 'DateTime'.`:

[image]

This is because I stated that last day elements are of type `DateTime`.

Does luxon have its own format that I can import?

Or is there a way to create a datatime type for luxon, so you don't get the error.

Can you give me a hand?

Code:

```js
  const lNow = DateTime.now();
  const lThreeMonthsAgo = lNow.minus({month: 3}).startOf("week");
  let num = Math.ceil(lNow.diff(lThreeMonthsAgo, "days").days);
  let lastDays = [...Array(num).keys()].reduce(
      (acc, val) => [...acc, lThreeMonthsAgo.plus({day: val})],
      [] as Array<DateTime>
  );

  const month = lastDays.reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, val.c.month], [] as Array<number>);
  const unique_month = [...new Set(month)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with luxon, but the typings show that `year`, `month`, etc. are declared as accessors, so you can just index directly them on a `DateTime` object, i.e. replace `val.c.month` with `val.month`.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCIEMYFMAqp0F84BmUEIcA5ADYCuAHhAHZkCwAUKwMYMDO8FAchADucALxxUGbCHQA6ekIAUASgDcHbr0wALKOnQBZBjC1cAggHMIouPyEyQwelS4KEII1oBccAMy4lMjwosADyBAoARIJ6ANYRqqwU6PBOpGL6aFoy7OjAFAq2gjIAJsAE4RTaugYeZpYANHARxSgAnlzxJW1cCSxJvCg8qO3WANoyE6ZQUG0KqQEx6O3KALoyusVUOQqscHtwCijs7I0AbigUSqIAfHDjE0cnNlV6hvTGdRAyYNQuCC2tbznCj%20Fb1Xb7UYrOCDOBTGatAA8EiwOGurF66noPDg7neWmsFEGMGGXHW6E220OxzOFyuIlu9xkj1pFHsHjBd2hsPhbURqQARugoNdepxsfAqPRgABHKjoAD6eOMYwmcnQwgAyskFMqtEoVmoWEA)